# Magento2 : Plugin for send email function

Tags: magento2, plugin, send-mail

i'm trying to make plugin to custom email function, i need to create two field more first name and last name.I need to use plugin to get value of the first-name and last-name. When sending email, the value of two field will be showed. I do not know how to do it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You wants to send custom email right? in Magento2 or 1?

Comment: magento2. Thanks ^_^

Comment: To create Custom Email template in custom Module Please find the below link: [http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/](http://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/)

Comment: please elaborate on which action you want to send email and who do you want to send email customer or admin

Comment: sorry for not describing detail, i want to create 2 fields first name and last name in contact us page and using plugin to get the value of first name and last name so that when sending email the 2 fields will be showed. Of course sending for admin